# Mutable AST vs. different immutable ASTs

Tags: data-structures, compiler

I am writing a toy compiler. During the semantic passes, I want to add information to the AST. Which of the following is the best approach?

- Define 1 mutable AST type whose fields are updated with each pass
- Define multiple immutable ASTs, each of which are an input and output of a semantic pass
- A mix of both?

Comment: +1 I have written compilers and seen compiler written with both approaches, and I would love to hear a community consensus on this question!

Comment: Well I'm off the opinion that each AST for each different intermediate language ought to be different types, so for each "non-optimization" pass you'll have to output a new one anyways so those may as well be immutable. For optimizations, I could see an argument in either direction depending on the language: it's generally simpler to construct a new AST (you don't have to worry about losing information you need) but not all languages take kindly to so much allocation.

Comment: It's an abstract *syntax* tree. Why in hell would you output a *syntax* tree from a *semantic* pass?

Comment: @DeadMG Because some semantic analyses need to annotate basically every part of the program (with a type, for example) and preserve the syntactic structure for later passes? This is standard practice in compiler construction as far as I know.

Comment: This simply raises the further question as to why the fuck any later passes care in the slightest about the syntax of the matter. For basically every program there are innumerable ways of syntactically specifying identical semantics. Furthermore, any such tree would not be a syntax tree, it would be a semantic tree with a pointer back to the original syntax tree.

Comment: @DeadMG The easiest example to defend would be if the semantic analysis is split in multiple passes (e.g., name resolution, then type inference). And it's pointless to argue whether this is a "semantic tree" or a "syntax tree". It contains all the original structure and nodes of the AST, though augmented with additional data, that's good enough for me.

Comment: You may find this approach interesting: http://andykeep.com/pubs/np-preprint.pdf - define as many slightly different immutable ASTs and IRs as you like, the more the better, and put stupidly trivial passes in between them.

Comment: @DeadMG, intermediate languages got a syntax too.

Comment: @SK-logic: Depends on exactly how intermediate they are. My compiler has several intermediate trees that don't have any syntax.

Comment: Of course it depends on an approach. If you employ the nanopass approach I referred to, all your intermediate step will have a representable (S-expressions-based) syntax. It's just a different way of thinking about the compilation pipeline.

Comment: @delnan: The argument between "semantic tree" and "syntax tree" is *literally this entire question*.

Comment: @DeadMG, there is no argument. It's just two different approaches, two cultures that don't even overlap. There's also a third, totally alien culture - *attribute grammars*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what information you want to add, if your AST is self contained well, how many passes you'll make where you modify the AST, and a handful of other conditions which may or may not matter for you.

In general, I would try to avoid modifying the AST. That can easily get you into the situation where your code needs to start caring what state the AST is in (is the added info missing, or just not added yet?). That sort of temporal coupling is troublesome in any software, along with the usual issues that accompany mutable state.

Answer (score 2):

Syntax trees should be immutable. Otherwise, they are clearly a lie.

The syntax tree represents the syntactic input of the user- so unless you're going to go and mutate their source code text, it's a complete non-starter to mutate the tree.

If the semantic passes need to work with a tree, they need their own semantic tree. Arbitrarily re-using a completely different tree that has a completely different purpose and fundamental meaning is a bad plan.

Semantic trees aren't really trees at all anyway, it's trivial to produce programs with e.g. recursive functions that are graphs, whereas syntax trees actually are trees.